# SQL Server 2008 - Hierarchyid Error - what is the max size of hierarchyid in characters?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I got this error running a query that construct a hierarchyid column:

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "hierarchyid":
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.HierarchyIdException: 24001: SqlHierarchyId.Parse failed because the input string '/5290/6949/10926/14876/20843/26843/28099/33588/38299/39741/47206/49611/52487/55609/59735/68055/70899/72381/78691/82814/85883/93033/95161/100079/102349/108741/111671/117872/119889/121814/130278/133965/136834/141114/142768/151363/155136/157479/162695/164712/173269/176216/181110/185106/188492/189918/192074/193487/199606/202735/206413/207686/209230/211408/212295/215368/219305/224508/229598/235226/240175/244124/246944/248179/257451/261184/263979/266305/272088/278354/281525/286249/289684/292710/296042/297599/302251/308114/312144/313236/317958/323033/327665/328409/333567/337567/339560/343634/348692/352779/353201/362728/363987/370922/374911/376380/379496/383826/387374/391564/396844/399291/401406/406782/407365/412686/417188/419928/423104/425405/429919/436682/442219/443747/445901/448487/450157/457585/461898/464457/465557/471344/474244/476760/482003/485286/488836/491782/494581/500245/504695/507120/508621/512440/517214/521317/523267/528125/530206/534123/537417/543297/545193/550357/553120/557276/558422/561827/568206/571099/572783/576088/580839/584166/591023/593629/595246/601567/603921/608035/611395/615540/617236/620724/628276/632162/' is not a valid string representation of a SqlHierarchyId node.
>
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.HierarchyIdException:
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.ex_raise(Int32 major, Int32 minor, Int32 sev, Int32 state, Object param1, Object param2, Object param3)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OrdPath.InitFromString(String chDottedString)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId.Parse(SqlString input)

The lines from code that probably cause the error are inside a CTE

```
cast ('/' + cast(ROWNUM as varchar(max)) + '/' as hierarchyid) nodeid
...
cast (cast(r.nodeid.ToString() as varchar(max))+ cast(f.ROWNUM as varchar(max)) + '/' as hierarchyid) nodeid
```

I fixed my problem by constructing the `hierarchyid` using another column that has smaller values (so the depth is the same just the integer values are smaller), this was possible by reworking my query to use a composite key, so my `nodeid` is no longer unique on its own, I need to combine it with the Employee ID, this in a way meant my `nodeid` became partitioned per Employee

Anyway, I still want to know why am I getting this error, the Microsoft Documentation says

> The encoding used in the hierarchyid type is limited to 892 bytes. Consequently, nodes which have too many levels in their representation to fit into 892 bytes cannot be represented by the hierarchyid type.

Does that mean that the maximum size of hierarchyid is 892 characters? What am I missing, how should calculate the path or key size?

The key/path in my error is 1139 characters, what is the max size of hierarchyid in characters?

Comment: Have a look at the `Extremely compact` paragraph in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: @HABO I read it but didnt understand much, do you think you can elaborate on this section, simplify it maybe

Comment: Not of a solution, but curiosity has me - what are you trying to represent that has a hierarchy depth of 167 levels?

Comment: @BenThul 

It is an activity table 
I was asked to highlight employees who had 3 or more days where they were
no call no show.

To properly create the sequence you cannot delete other types of days, 
days in sequence can be interrupted by weekends or vacation, or days where the employee is not schedule to work, so I cannot just use calendar days sequences. 

The 167 is 167 working days not interrupted by absence  (they may have been interrupted by vacations thought)

It was fun writing the query

Comment: Got it. That sounds like a "gaps and islands" problem to me possibly using a calendar table to help in what should be considered a working day.